# Storm spout directly from MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, hadoop, real-time, apache-storm

I want to use a Storm cluster to monitor user activity real time. Currently, the user activity log is saved in MySQL. There are about 100,000 records recorded to MySQL every minute and 20,000,000 records everyday. I want to do a topN viewed items rank every N minutes. How to design the spout for this? Should I query directly from MySQL in the spout or use a message queue like Kafka? I want real time performance so prefer the first way. But I found rare production implementation choose this way. Why?

Comment: I will write them into kafka, then consumed by storm, and write to mysql in a storm bolt if needed.

Comment: how about tailing mysql log and saving it to message queeu, then make storm consume messages from this queue and process them

Answer (score 0):

To emit tuples directly from MySql Bin Logs, you can probably use this mysql spout on github(https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/storm-mysql).
This spout would emit your row updates as a stream. This spout uses the brilliant Open Replicator(https://github.com/whitesock/open-replicator) to tail bin logs.

For your use case, then probably write a bolt similar to this:
https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter/blob/master/src/jvm/storm/starter/RollingTopWords.java

This approach removes the need for message queuing and more moving parts.

Disclaimer: Author of the Mysql Spout mentioned above.